# helm-multi-occur, navigate through the search occurrences

Tags: helm, occur

I use `helm-multi-occur` to search for a pattern in all open buffers. Search results are displayed line by line in the buffer `*helm multi occur*`.

When i press enter after selecting an item, it enters a newline instead of taking me to the source code, where that pattern is located.

Screenshot is,

[image: helm]

Here pressing enter on the green bar adds more and more blank lines, but i would like to switch the buffer to `buttopane.js-ln#86`.

Comment: The buffer `*helm multi occur*` (or any other helm buffers) is not designed to operate directly by user, I guess you might switch to that buffer by mistake/accident.  If you think it may be a bug of helm, you'd better report it to the helm project, don't forget to tell others how to reproduce it with a clean Emacs config (see also https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/wiki#debugging).

Answer (score 3):

If you want another way to do this, you can use [Icicles](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles).  A non-negative prefix arg with command [`icicle-occur`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview) (`C-c '`) searches multiple buffers line by line (like `occur`, `moccur`, and `grep`).  If you hit `C-!` at the prompt that asks which buffers then all buffers are searched.

```
C-9 C-c ' C-! RET
```

Here, `C-9` says search multiple buffers. `C-c '` is `icicle-occur`, which is a line-by-line search, like `grep`.  `C-!` says choose all candidates (the candidates are the existing buffers).  `RET` ends choosing buffers.

Then you type whatever search patterns you want.  The search hits are shown in popup buffer `*Completions*`.  Change your minibuffer input and the matching hits change.  Use `S-SPC` to lock in one pattern and add an additional pattern to match.  You can use `down` to cycle among candidates or continue to narrow the choices.  You can cycle showing the matches in context in the buffers, using `C-down`.

Each search candidate is a buffer line followed by the buffer name.  You can match both if you like.  Matching can be using any number of search patterns (separated using `S-SPC`), and each pattern can be a regexp (or other kinds of patterns).